# Split environment causing chaotic alignments

Tags: equations, align, split

I am having some trouble trying to split my equations to get the desired effect that I want. The first picture is how I want to be able to align my equations, the only difference is that in the first picture I have page margins set to 0.45in and now I need to have them set to 1.0in.

[image]

When I adjust the margins to 1.0 in with the code below, I get the second picture where the equation number is being pushed down to the next line  because  the expression on the first line is too long:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.45in, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ stmaryrd }
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \min_{L_{t}} \quad & \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J \hspace{0.5em}\beta^{t-1} \left[  (c + p\thinspace\tau\thinspace\alpha^{(i,j)} + f^{h}) L_{t}^{(i,j)}G_{t,NewGrowth}^{(i,j)}  + \alpha^{(i,j)}(\tilde{f} + p\tau)\thinspace G_{t,PostTreatment}^{(i,j)}\right]\\[5pt]
    \text{s.t.} \quad & B_{t,PreDispersal}^{(i,j)} = \rho G_{t-1,PostTreatment}^{(i,j)} & \forall i,j,t \quad \tag{1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture 2]

I know that I have to use a `split` or `multline` environment, but everytime that I do my equations just blow up off of the page or their alignment becomes chaotic. Here is an example with the `split` environment.

Ideally I would like to be able to split the first expression into two lines and have the equations numbers lined up and not pushed down to the lines below. 
[image]

Comment: Change `& \forall` to `\qquad \forall`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no need for the `&` symbol before `\forall i,j,t` in the second row. A `\quad` or `\qquad` spacing directive should suffice.

I would use an `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment; this setup generates a single equation number, with the optional argument of `aligned` (`[t]` or `[b]` indicating whether the equation number should be placed at the top or bottom. The default is `[c]` -- in which case you could also use a `split` environment in place of the `aligned` environment.

In the following, I've set `{aligned}[b]`, removed all thinspace directives (`\thinspace` and `\,`), rendered the variable names -- `NewGrowth` etc -- used in various subscripts in the upright Roman font via `\mathrm`, and loaded the `mleftright` package to fix some horizontal-spacing issues associated with the use of `\left` and `\right`.

An additional suggestion: You may want to think about indicating whether the minimization should be carried out over `L_{t}` or `L_{t}^{(i,j)}`;  the latter would indicate that there are `I\times J\timesT` rather than just `T` choice variables, right? Maybe this point will be utterly obvious to your readers. On the off chance, though, that some of your readers aren't quite up to speed, writing `L_{t}^{(i,j)}` might just provide them with an extra bit of clarity.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mleftright}\mleftright
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1in, includefoot]{geometry} % note: "1in"
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex} % fix some issues with Latin Modern's scalable operators
\usepackage{enumitem,stmaryrd,comment}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
%%%%%%\usepackage{xcolor} % don't load packages more than once
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b] % 'b' to place eq. number at bottom-right of env.
    \min_{L_{t}}\quad & \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{i=1}^I \sum_{j=1}^J 
         \beta^{t-1} \left[ (c + p\tau\alpha^{(i,j)} 
         + f^{h}) L_{t}^{(i,j)} 
         G_{t,\mathrm{NewGrowth}}^{(i,j)}  
         + \alpha^{(i,j)}(\tilde{f} + p\tau) 
         G_{t,\mathrm{PostTreatment}}^{(i,j)} \right] \\[1ex]
    \text{s.t.}\quad & B_{t,\mathrm{PreDispersal}}^{(i,j)} = 
        \rho G_{t-1,\mathrm{PostTreatment}}^{(i,j)} 
        \quad \forall i,j,t 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `split` . You forgot to tell the OP that you removed all spacing directives (I agree with you, of course). Also, when `lmodern` is used, I recommend `\usepackage{fixcmex}` to get scalable big operators.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for these comments and suggestions. I've updated my answer in several places to incorporate your observations.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Still getting the hang of LaTeX so it's appreciated.